# Kotlin: How to wait for a coroutine from non-suspend without runBlocking?

Tags: kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

**Edit 2:** I think I misunderstood the documentation. I read:

> **runBlocking**
>
> This function should not be used from a coroutine. It is designed to bridge regular blocking code to libraries that are written in suspending style, to be used in `main` functions and in tests.

To mean that I shouldn't use `runBlocking()` at all other than for `main` or tests. But I now realise I read it wrong, specifically this part:

> **It is designed to bridge regular blocking code to libraries that are written in suspending style**

So it seems that runBlocking **should** be used in this scenario.

However I think I should fully grok the topic of contexts to see which contexts is best suited to pass to runBlocking in this case:

```
return runBlocking(???????) {
    job1.await() + job2.await()
}
```

---

**Edit:** Clearly I phrased the question badly as all attempts to answer it miss the actual question and the constraint I am posing. So let's try a different approach...

This works:

```
fun doSomething(): Int {
    val job1 = GlobalScope.async { calculateSomething() }
    val job2 = GlobalScope.async { calculateSomething() }
    return runBlocking {
        job1.await() + job2.await()
    }
}

suspend fun calculateSomething(): Int {
    delay(1000L)
    return 13
}

suspend fun calculateSomethingElse(): Int {
    delay(2000L)
    return 19
}
```

My question is: is there anyway I can achieve the same result:

1. **Without** using `runBlocking()` at all.
2. **Without** turning `doSomething()` into a `suspend` function.

?

In other words: is there anything I can put instead of `??????` to make the following work?

```
fun doSomething(): Int {
    val job1 = GlobalScope.async { calculateSomething() }
    val job2 = GlobalScope.async { calculateSomething() }
    return ????????? {
        job1.?????() + job2.?????()
    }
}

suspend fun calculateSomething(): Int {
    delay(1000L)
    return 13
}

suspend fun calculateSomethingElse(): Int {
    delay(2000L)
    return 19
}
```

---

<strike>I have a small utility method that runs any given external command and returns its output (i.e small wrapper around Java Process API):</strike>

```
class RunningCommand(private val proc: Process) {

    fun waitFor(): String {
        proc.outputStream.close()

        var output = ""
        val outputRdr = thread { output = proc.inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() } }
        var error = ""
        val errorRdr = thread { error = proc.errorStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() } }

        proc.waitFor()

        outputRdr.join()
        errorRdr.join()

        if (proc.exitValue() != 0) {
            throw RuntimeException("Command returned non-zero status: $output$error")
        }

        return output
    }
}
```

This code works correctly. However it creates two additional threads for each command execution. I wanted to avoid that by switching to coroutines. I was able to do this, but I had to use `runBlocking`:

```
class RunningCommand(private val proc: Process) {

    fun waitFor(): String {
        proc.outputStream.close()

        var output = ""
        val outputRdr = GlobalScope.async { output = proc.inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() } }
        var error = ""
        val errorRdr = GlobalScope.async { error = proc.errorStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() } }

        proc.waitFor()

        runBlocking {
            outputRdr.await()
            errorRdr.await()
        }

        if (proc.exitValue() != 0) {
            throw RuntimeException("Command returned non-zero status: $output${error}")
        }

        return output
    }
}
```

This code also works, but I read that `runBlocking` should only be used on `main()` methods and tests, i.e not meant to be used in this way. Peeking at its implementation it looks horrible and indeed looks like something one wouldn't want to call repeatedly from some utility method.

**So my question is:** how else am I supposed to bridge the gap between blocking code and coroutines? Or put differently, what is the correct way to wait for a `suspend` function from non-`suspend` code?

Or is it simply that my design is wrong, and to use Coroutines anywhere down the line I need to make the `main()` method `runBlocking` and essentially always be inside some coroutine scope?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For any future travellers who make the same mistake as me - `runBlocking` is OK to use not just in `main` / tests - but also:

> It is designed to bridge regular blocking code to libraries that are written in suspending style

Somehow I got the impression that it is evil to use for just some library function, but it is not.

Comment: Please also note that your original example with two `async()` in the global scope suffers from a problem that the coroutines are unrelated - if one of them fails, another one might still be running as it's completely independent of everything and is bound only to the global scope

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own scope with dispatchers that do operations in the background. You can use withContext if you want to wait for something to completely finish executing.

```
private val myScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main) 

myScope.launch {

   withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        //to stuff in the background
    }

}
```

You run the code bellow, you'll see that it prints 20, not null.

```
fun main() {
    callSuspendFun()
}

suspend fun doWorkAndReturnDouble(num: Int): Int {
    delay(1000)
    return num * 2
}

fun callSuspendFun() {
    val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
    coroutineScope.launch {
        var num: Int? = null
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val newNum = 10
            num = doWorkAndReturnDouble(newNum)
        }
        println(num)
    }
}
```

So to call a suspend function from a non-suspend function, without using runBlocking, you have to create a coroutine scope. And withContext you wait for the execution of the code.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - can you change your example to show how you wait for a coroutine or suspend function from a non-suspend function without using `runBlocking`?

Comment: I've added an example that you can run on yourself. Hope it helps more.

Comment: I don't think you fully understood my question. I need the blocking / non-suspend code to block and wait for the coroutine to finish, and get its result. If I understand correctly, what you've done here is demonstrate how you can launch a coroutine from non-suspend code in a "fire and forget" fashion...

Answer (score -1):

You should use `coroutineScope`

```
suspend fun waitFor(): String = coroutineScope {
    proc.outputStream.close()

    var output = ""
    val outputRdr = async { output = proc.inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() } }
    var error = ""
    val errorRdr = async { error = proc.errorStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() } }

    proc.waitFor()

        outputRdr.await()
        errorRdr.await()

    if (proc.exitValue() != 0) {
        throw RuntimeException("Command returned non-zero status: $output${error}")
    }

    return output
}
```

Comment: Again - this means `waitFor()` is now a `suspend` method. `waitFor()` is called from a non-`suspend` method. How do I make that caller wait for `waitFor()`'s result?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `CoroutineScope()` with `Dispathers.IO` which will launch a coroutine in background thread and would offload your execution on that thread

```
class RunningCommand(private val proc: Process) {

fun waitFor(): String {
    // Starting a new coroutine on Background thread (IO)
    proc.outputStream.close()
    var output = ""
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Unconfined).async {

        val outputRdr = async { output = proc.inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() } }
        var error = ""
        val errorRdr = async { error = proc.errorStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() } }

        proc.waitFor()

        // No need of runBlocking 
        // await() call would wait for completion of its async block
        outputRdr.await() // Execution would block until outputRdr block completion on IO thread
        // At this stage, outputRdr block is completed
        errorRdr.await() // Execution would block until errorRdr block completion on IO thread
        // At this stage, errorRdr block is completed


        if (proc.exitValue() != 0) {
            throw RuntimeException("Command returned non-zero status: $output${error}")
        }
    return@async output
    }
    return output
}

}
```

Note : If you're calling `waitFor()` method from any coroutine context, you can carry on work on same coroutine context by writing `coroutineScope { }` instead of `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { }`, managing structured concurrency properly.

Comment: This code does not compile. `waitFor()` now does not return anything. Furthermore the lines of `proc.outputStream.close()` and `proc.waitFor()` now generate a warning "inappropriate blocking method call". Also the return statement is not accepted as the launch block is of type `CoroutineScope.() -> Unit`.

Comment: I've corrected errors. `proc.outputStream.close()` was giving warning of blocking call, so I put it outside and above coroutine scope. I've handled return value error also

Comment: If you want to get proper `output` returned from `waitFor()`, you need to make this function suspend. Currently, `output` value will not match with correct value, as `return output` line is not waiting for launched coroutine's completion

Comment: @AmirAbiri : I've edited my code to handle that case also. Now, `output` with proper value would get returned. Plus, `waitFor()` is non-suspend function. Please run this code.

Comment: That doesn't work either - `waitFor()` simply returns `""` immediately.

Comment: Then there is some problem in writing value to `output`. Can you re-check it or debug it or log it?