# How to skip delay in unit tests

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing

I am trying to skip the delay when running unit test.

I found about `runTest` from kotlinx.coroutines.test but it does not work.

What is wrong in the code? The code waits for 3 seconds instead of skipping the delay.

Code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import kotlinx.coroutines.test.runTest
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import org.mockito.Mockito.*

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
class KotlinTestSkipDelay {


  @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
  @Test
  fun `skip delay`() {
    runTest {
      println("start")
      println(LocalDateTime.now())

      delayTest()

      println("end")
      println(LocalDateTime.now())
    }

  }

  private fun delayTest() { //System under test so cannot change
    runBlocking {
      delay(3000L)
    }
  }
}
```

The actual code in my application needs a delay so it uses runBlocking(). There is no `suspend` function and the delay() is called from a normal method and not inside a coroutine scope. Similar to the `delayTest()` method shown in unit test. How can I skip this delay when testing this code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59528802/kotlin-how-to-wait-for-a-coroutine-from-non-suspend-without-runblocking

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-make-sense-of-kotlin-coroutines-b666c7151b93

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you use `runBlocking()` in `delayTest()`. It starts an entirely new coroutine which doesn't know about the `runTest()`. As the name of the function `runBlocking()` suggests, it blocks the current thread.

Solution to the problem depends on your specific case. The above code seems like a minimum example to reproduce the problem, so your specific case may be much more complicated. But generally, if `delayTest()` is invoked from coroutines and it is going to wait on something, then it should be a suspend function and should never block:

```kotlin
private suspend fun delayTest() {
  delay(3000L)
}
```

If you use `runBlocking()` across your code, potentially invoking it from coroutines, then you may get much bigger problems than that, including reduced performance or even deadlocks during runtime. This is one of reasons why using `runBlocking()` commonly in the code is generally discouraged.

Comment: That is true for anything but unit tests, because it is against unit test principles. The unit test must be straight forward, the unit test must not do any heavy computational work or something complex, the fact that you do that means that your logic is not designed very well. We are totally safe to use `runBlocking()` in unit tests, we must avoid parallel execution in unit tests because that will make it an integration test, right?

Comment: The actual code needs a delay so it uses runBlocking(). There is no suspend function and the delay() is called from a normal method and not inside a coroutine scope. Similar to the delayTest() method shown in unit test. This is a valid scenario to use `runBlocking()` in Production code right? If not, how else can I call `delay()` in Production code?

Comment: @firstpostcommenter There is nothing wrong in using `runBlocking()` itself, but we should avoid invoking it from a coroutine - this is mentioned implicitly in the documentation. The reason is that we shouldn't block threads when inside a coroutine and `runBlocking()` obviously blocks the thread. This may cause performance problems at runtime.

Comment: Clear. And in the unit test I was using `runTest`(a coroutine scope) which in-turn calls `runBlocking` because I was thinking it will skip delay which is not the case. So `runTest` is useless here and I will remove it. Not sure how to skip the delay now in unit test. (I cannot change production code as a `suspend` function because Production code seems to be using `runBlocking` without `suspend` which is a valid situation).

Comment: I will repeat my answer which has for some reason been downvoted: You need to use a `TestCoroutineScheduler` which allows you to control the coroutines in your test and do things like `advanceUntilIdle` to skip `delay` calls. Explained here:
https://kt.academy/article/cc-testing

Comment: @dominicoder "_which has for some reason been downvoted_" -- My guess, probably because your answer is essentially a link-only answer.

Comment: @firstpostcommenter Generic answer is that the code you want to test has to be testable. This is not specific to coroutines. You would have similar problems If this code would use `Thread.sleep()`, send an HTTP request you can't control or simply be a tightly-coupled blob of multiple classes. If you can redesign the code to be more test-friendly, then I suggest to either make possible to test smaller suspend functions in separation; or make possible to inject the dispatcher used for `runBlocking()`.

Comment: In my actual application code, Even if I move the delay() to a separate suspend function how can I call it from the normal function without using runBlocking ()

Comment: If you can access that function from the test code, then you can use `runTest()` as you do already. `runTest()` is like an equivalent of `runBlocking()`, but which provides a simulated time flow. Or, as described in the article linked above, use `runBlocking()` in the test code, but inside it use `StandardTestDispatcher`.

Comment: Or if you don't ask about tests, but the main code. Well, that depends and can't be explained in a few sentences. General rule is that we should not switch between suspend and non-suspend back and forth. If we got to a coroutine context, stick to it. `runBlocking()` or similar should be used only on boundaries of our generally suspendable code. If we need to invoke a suspend function from outside and the caller expects that we wait by blocking the thread, then `runBlocking()` is the right choice. But we should not use this to switch to coroutine, then to regular code, then again to coroutine.

Answer (score 0):

The unit test must mock everything except the tested unit. If the tested unit adds some delays in his logic then there is nothing to do, the best you can do is to review your logic there, maybe you do something wrong and maybe you can decouple your testing unit by the unit that adds delay. After that you will be able to mock the unit that adds delay and remove the delay from there.

```kotlin
class MyRepo(val myServiceWithDelay: MyService) {
    suspend fun fetchData() {
        doSomeCoolJob()
        myServiceWithDelay.doSomeDelayedCoolJob()
    }
}

class MyRepoTest {
    private lateinit var classUnderTest: MyRepo
    @Mock
    private lateinit var myMockedService: MyService

    @Before
    fun setUp() { 
        classUnderTest = MyRepo(myMockedService)
    }
    @Test
    fun testMyCoolLogic() = runBlocking {
        Mockito.given(myMockedService.doSomeDelayedCoolJob()).thenMockItSomehowWithoutDelay()
        classUnderTest.fetchData() // now you have no delay
    }

}
```

In general the idea is to make our logic more unit test friendly :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to use a [TestCoroutineScheduler](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/-test-scope/test-scheduler.html). Read this:
https://kt.academy/article/cc-testing

EDIT: Example code based on comments:

```
fun main() {
  val job = GlobalScope.launch { // Launch Coroutine
    val result = suspendingSomething() // Call suspending function
    onSuspendingFunctionCompleted(result) // Call non-suspending function with result
  }

  // Call non-suspending function as usual
  onSuspendingFunctionCompleted(56)
}

fun onSuspendingFunctionCompleted(result: Int) {
  println("$result")
}

suspend fun suspendingSomething(): Int {
  delay(3000)
  return 42
}
```

Comment: The example does not show how to test a class that has regular non-suspend function with runBlocking{ delay(3000) } in it

Comment: You would not have a "regular non-suspend function with runBlocking" in it because you should only be using runBlocking for `main` and tests.

Comment: Then how can a normal function call and get the result of a suspend function?

Comment: suspend function are not intended to be called by and return a result to regular functions synchronously. That's - well - just regular programming. Your regular function would have to have a CoroutineScope to launch the suspend function in and a callback or something to handle the result once coroutine finishes.

Comment: And the callback() is a regular function and not a suspend function. In that case, Even with callback I don't see a way how I can get the output of a suspend function through the callback() to my regular function without using `runBlocking`. Do you have any example?

Comment: Updated answer with simple example.

Comment: The code does not print the result value i.e. 42. It only prints the hardcoded value 56. `launch` is fire and forget so you need `job.join()` to wait for the result and `join()` can only be called from another `suspend` function or a coroutine builder like `launch`, `async`, `withContext`, `runBlocking` etc

Comment: Right - that was a simple example. Your code would be presumably running in some ongoing process with a CoroutineScope in which to launch coroutines.

Comment: `runTest` from the OP already uses a `TestCoroutineScheduler`, that's not really the issue. The problem is that the OP's code "escapes" the test scheduler because it creates a separate context when using `runBlocking` in the middle. That's expained in @broot's answer.